# How to display Swfs in GTK3 Apps that is made out of html

Tags: gtk3, webkit

```
    view = WebKit.WebView()
    uri = 'transformice.html'
    uri = os.path.realpath(uri)
    uri = urllib.parse.ParseResult('file', '', uri, '', '', '')
    uri = urllib.parse.urlunparse(uri)
    view.load_uri(uri)
```

HTML:

```
<object id="swf1" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="Transformice" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="movie" value="TransformiceChargeur.swf" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#6A7495" />
<embed id="swf2" src="TransformiceChargeur.swf" wmode="direct" menu="true" quality="high" bgcolor="#6A7495" width="100%" height="100%" name="Transformice" align="middle" swLiveConnect="true" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

How to display SWFs from an object html within a GTK3/WebKit App cause currently this doesn't work. It shows A missing plugin thing so i assume there's a plugin i need to add of some sort.

Comment: If you have Flash installed, and plug-ins enabled, it should just work. Make sure you enable plug-in support in your WebView (I think it may be disabled by default).

Comment: How so????????????? @dobey

Comment: `view.get_settings().set_enable_plugins(true)` perhaps. I don't recall the exact method calls in Python. You need to get the WebKitSettings object, set the _enable-plugins_ property, and possibly set the settings on the WebView again to the modified WebKitSettings object. Documentation says it is enabled by default though. So perhaps you don't have Flash installed.

Comment: Which flash should i install @dobey

Comment: The `adobe-flashplugin` package should do.

Comment: I have that installed but i still have missing plugin error. I'm using version three of both GTK and Webkit. I also tried `view.get_settings().set_property("enable-plugins", True)` but still no results. @dobey

Comment: Here's the full code: https://hastebin.com/qefolifuko.py

Comment: I'm using Ububtu 16.04

Comment: Try loading about:plugins to see if it knows of Flash.

Comment: @dobey It does https://pastebin.com/raw/shTLkNiu

Comment: Running the html code in the browser works!

Comment: but i need it to work in gtk.

Comment: What is that paste from? I meant, load `about:plugins` in your app instead of your html file.